# Unable to find R package after installation

Tags: r, macos, installation, package

When I try to install the package `naniar` on MacOS, it installs to this location

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/xr/8_b5_mks1hg8hnch1c3w5rf80000gn/T/RtmpzdzhNV/downloaded_packages’
```

My `.libPath()` returns `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"`

I'm not sure why `install.packages(naniar)` is not installing to my library and I tried to install the dependencies for `naniar`. I have no idea where R is installing the package to. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The location is the standard location of macOS.

```
library()
Packages in library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library’:
```

Did you try this?:

```
install.packages("naniar")
library("naniar")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Yes I tried the above but it does not show naniar exists. Have also tried ```install.packages('naniar', dependencies = TRUE)``` and it also does not install the package to the standard location. I'm facing the same problem when trying ```install.packages('tidyverse')```, it's installing to this location  ```‘/private/var/folders/xr/8_b5_mks1hg8hnch1c3w5rf80000gn/T/RtmpzdzhNV/downloaded_packages’```